# The .NET Core SDK cannot be located

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, omnisharp

In vscode on my macbook running macos big sur i'm not able to use c# with the dotnet core in vs code, i keep getting this error(link to a picture down below). I tried countless things including appending the path that goes to the core to the bash_profile and uninstalling and reinstalling but nothing worked, please let me know if you have any solution, down below is a picture of the error and the full OmniSharp log

[image]

```html
Starting OmniSharp server at 5/16/2021, 10:06:20 PM
    Target: /Users/haardikgupta/Desktop/Code/CS

OmniSharp server started.
    Path: /Users/haardikgupta/.vscode/extensions/ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.23.11/.omnisharp/1.37.8/run
    PID: 61900

[info]: OmniSharp.Stdio.Host
        Starting OmniSharp on MacOS 11.2.3 (x64)
[info]: OmniSharp.Services.DotNetCliService
        DotNetPath set to dotnet
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.Discovery.MSBuildLocator
        Located 1 MSBuild instance(s)
            1: StandAlone 16.9.0 - "/Users/haardikgupta/.vscode/extensions/ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.23.11/.omnisharp/1.37.8/omnisharp/.msbuild/Current/Bin"
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.Discovery.MSBuildLocator
        MSBUILD_EXE_PATH environment variable set to '/Users/haardikgupta/.vscode/extensions/ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.23.11/.omnisharp/1.37.8/omnisharp/.msbuild/Current/Bin/MSBuild.exe'
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.Discovery.MSBuildLocator
        Registered MSBuild instance: StandAlone 16.9.0 - "/Users/haardikgupta/.vscode/extensions/ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.23.11/.omnisharp/1.37.8/omnisharp/.msbuild/Current/Bin"
            CscToolExe = csc.exe
            MSBuildToolsPath = /Users/haardikgupta/.vscode/extensions/ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.23.11/.omnisharp/1.37.8/omnisharp/.msbuild/Current/Bin
            CscToolPath = /Users/haardikgupta/.vscode/extensions/ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.23.11/.omnisharp/1.37.8/omnisharp/.msbuild/Current/Bin/Roslyn
            BypassFrameworkInstallChecks = true
            MSBuildExtensionsPath = /Users/haardikgupta/.vscode/extensions/ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.23.11/.omnisharp/1.37.8/omnisharp/.msbuild
[info]: OmniSharp.WorkspaceInitializer
        Invoking Workspace Options Provider: OmniSharp.Roslyn.CSharp.Services.CSharpFormattingWorkspaceOptionsProvider, Order: 0
[info]: OmniSharp.WorkspaceInitializer
        Invoking Workspace Options Provider: OmniSharp.Roslyn.CSharp.Services.Completion.CompletionOptionsProvider, Order: 0
[info]: OmniSharp.WorkspaceInitializer
        Invoking Workspace Options Provider: OmniSharp.Roslyn.CSharp.Services.RenameWorkspaceOptionsProvider, Order: 100
[info]: OmniSharp.WorkspaceInitializer
        Invoking Workspace Options Provider: OmniSharp.Roslyn.CSharp.Services.ImplementTypeWorkspaceOptionsProvider, Order: 110
[info]: OmniSharp.WorkspaceInitializer
        Invoking Workspace Options Provider: OmniSharp.Roslyn.CSharp.Services.BlockStructureWorkspaceOptionsProvider, Order: 140
[info]: OmniSharp.Cake.CakeProjectSystem
        Detecting Cake files in '/Users/haardikgupta/Desktop/Code/CS'.
[info]: OmniSharp.Cake.CakeProjectSystem
        Could not find any Cake files
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectSystem
        No solution files found in '/Users/haardikgupta/Desktop/Code/CS'
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Queue project update for '/Users/haardikgupta/Desktop/Code/CS/CS.csproj'
[info]: OmniSharp.Script.ScriptProjectSystem
        Detecting CSX files in '/Users/haardikgupta/Desktop/Code/CS'.
[info]: OmniSharp.Script.ScriptProjectSystem
        Could not find any CSX files
[info]: OmniSharp.WorkspaceInitializer
        Configuration finished.
[info]: OmniSharp.Stdio.Host
        Omnisharp server running using Stdio at location '/Users/haardikgupta/Desktop/Code/CS' on host 61839.
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Loading project: /Users/haardikgupta/Desktop/Code/CS/CS.csproj
It was not possible to find any installed .NET SDKs.
Install a .NET SDK from:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet-download
It was not possible to find any installed .NET SDKs.
Install a .NET SDK from:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet-download
[warn]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Failed to load project file '/Users/haardikgupta/Desktop/Code/CS/CS.csproj'.
/Users/haardikgupta/Desktop/Code/CS/CS.csproj(0,0)
Microsoft.Build.Exceptions.InvalidProjectFileException: The SDK 'Microsoft.NET.Sdk' specified could not be found.  /Users/haardikgupta/Desktop/Code/CS/CS.csproj
  at Microsoft.Build.Shared.ProjectErrorUtilities.ThrowInvalidProject (System.String errorSubCategoryResourceName, Microsoft.Build.Shared.IElementLocation elementLocation, System.String resourceName, System.Object[] args) [0x00040] in <ea47b2df30ad4051b6681ba57ba83dc9>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.Shared.ProjectErrorUtilities.VerifyThrowInvalidProject[T1] (System.Boolean condition, System.String errorSubCategoryResourceName, Microsoft.Build.Shared.IElementLocation elementLocation, System.String resourceName, T1 arg0) [0x00003] in <ea47b2df30ad4051b6681ba57ba83dc9>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.Shared.ProjectErrorUtilities.ThrowInvalidProject[T1] (Microsoft.Build.Shared.IElementLocation elementLocation, System.String resourceName, T1 arg0) [0x00000] in <ea47b2df30ad4051b6681ba57ba83dc9>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Evaluator`4[P,I,M,D].ExpandAndLoadImportsFromUnescapedImportExpressionConditioned (System.String directoryOfImportingFile, Microsoft.Build.Construction.ProjectImportElement importElement, System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Microsoft.Build.Construction.ProjectRootElement]& projects, Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.SdkResolution.SdkResult& sdkResult, System.Boolean throwOnFileNotExistsError) [0x00309] in <ea47b2df30ad4051b6681ba57ba83dc9>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Evaluator`4[P,I,M,D].ExpandAndLoadImports (System.String directoryOfImportingFile, Microsoft.Build.Construction.ProjectImportElement importElement, Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.SdkResolution.SdkResult& sdkResult) [0x00027] in <ea47b2df30ad4051b6681ba57ba83dc9>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Evaluator`4[P,I,M,D].EvaluateImportElement (System.String directoryOfImportingFile, Microsoft.Build.Construction.ProjectImportElement importElement) [0x0000d] in <ea47b2df30ad4051b6681ba57ba83dc9>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Evaluator`4[P,I,M,D].PerformDepthFirstPass (Microsoft.Build.Construction.ProjectRootElement currentProjectOrImport) [0x000e6] in <ea47b2df30ad4051b6681ba57ba83dc9>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Evaluator`4[P,I,M,D].Evaluate () [0x00139] in <ea47b2df30ad4051b6681ba57ba83dc9>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Evaluator`4[P,I,M,D].Evaluate (Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.IEvaluatorData`4[P,I,M,D] data, Microsoft.Build.Construction.ProjectRootElement root, Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectLoadSettings loadSettings, System.Int32 maxNodeCount, Microsoft.Build.Collections.PropertyDictionary`1[T] environmentProperties, Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.Logging.ILoggingService loggingService, Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.IItemFactory`2[S,T] itemFactory, Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.IToolsetProvider toolsetProvider, Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectRootElementCacheBase projectRootElementCache, Microsoft.Build.Framework.BuildEventContext buildEventContext, Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.SdkResolution.ISdkResolverService sdkResolverService, System.Int32 submissionId, Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Context.EvaluationContext evaluationContext, System.Boolean interactive) [0x00047] in <ea47b2df30ad4051b6681ba57ba83dc9>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project+ProjectImpl.Reevaluate (Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.Logging.ILoggingService loggingServiceForEvaluation, Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectLoadSettings loadSettings, Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Context.EvaluationContext evaluationContext) [0x00063] in <ea47b2df30ad4051b6681ba57ba83dc9>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project+ProjectImpl.ReevaluateIfNecessary (Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.Logging.ILoggingService loggingServiceForEvaluation, Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectLoadSettings loadSettings, Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Context.EvaluationContext evaluationContext) [0x00035] in <ea47b2df30ad4051b6681ba57ba83dc9>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project+ProjectImpl.ReevaluateIfNecessary (Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.Logging.ILoggingService loggingServiceForEvaluation, Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Context.EvaluationContext evaluationContext) [0x00000] in <ea47b2df30ad4051b6681ba57ba83dc9>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project+ProjectImpl.ReevaluateIfNecessary (Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Context.EvaluationContext evaluationContext) [0x00007] in <ea47b2df30ad4051b6681ba57ba83dc9>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project+ProjectImpl.Initialize (System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[TKey,TValue] globalProperties, System.String toolsVersion, System.String subToolsetVersion, Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectLoadSettings loadSettings, Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Context.EvaluationContext evaluationContext) [0x00127] in <ea47b2df30ad4051b6681ba57ba83dc9>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project..ctor (System.String projectFile, System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[TKey,TValue] globalProperties, System.String toolsVersion, System.String subToolsetVersion, Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectCollection projectCollection, Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectLoadSettings loadSettings, Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Context.EvaluationContext evaluationContext) [0x00073] in <ea47b2df30ad4051b6681ba57ba83dc9>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project..ctor (System.String projectFile, System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[TKey,TValue] globalProperties, System.String toolsVersion, System.String subToolsetVersion, Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectCollection projectCollection, Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectLoadSettings loadSettings) [0x00000] in <ea47b2df30ad4051b6681ba57ba83dc9>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project..ctor (System.String projectFile, System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[TKey,TValue] globalProperties, System.String toolsVersion, Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectCollection projectCollection, Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectLoadSettings loadSettings) [0x00000] in <ea47b2df30ad4051b6681ba57ba83dc9>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project..ctor (System.String projectFile, System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[TKey,TValue] globalProperties, System.String toolsVersion, Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectCollection projectCollection) [0x00000] in <ea47b2df30ad4051b6681ba57ba83dc9>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectCollection.LoadProject (System.String fileName, System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[TKey,TValue] globalProperties, System.String toolsVersion) [0x000f7] in <ea47b2df30ad4051b6681ba57ba83dc9>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectCollection.LoadProject (System.String fileName, System.String toolsVersion) [0x00000] in <ea47b2df30ad4051b6681ba57ba83dc9>:0 
  at OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectLoader.EvaluateProjectFileCore (System.String filePath, System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyDictionary`2[TKey,TValue] projectConfigurationsInSolution) [0x00160] in <9ecc61c9716b45d19f58afb1114317db>:0 
  at OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectLoader.BuildProject (System.String filePath, System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyDictionary`2[TKey,TValue] configurationsInSolution) [0x0000d] in <9ecc61c9716b45d19f58afb1114317db>:0 
  at OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectFile.ProjectFileInfo.Load (System.String filePath, OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectIdInfo projectIdInfo, OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectLoader loader, System.Guid sessionId, OmniSharp.Services.DotNetInfo dotNetInfo) [0x00023] in <9ecc61c9716b45d19f58afb1114317db>:0 
  at OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager+<>c__DisplayClass31_0.<LoadProject>b__0 () [0x00000] in <9ecc61c9716b45d19f58afb1114317db>:0 
  at (wrapper delegate-invoke) System.Func`1[System.ValueTuple`3[OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectFile.ProjectFileInfo,System.Collections.Immutable.ImmutableArray`1[OmniSharp.MSBuild.Logging.MSBuildDiagnostic],OmniSharp.MSBuild.Notification.ProjectLoadedEventArgs]].invoke_TResult()
  at OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager.LoadOrReloadProject (System.String projectFilePath, System.Func`1[TResult] loader) [0x0001b] in <9ecc61c9716b45d19f58afb1114317db>:0 

[fail]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Attempted to update project that is not loaded: /Users/haardikgupta/Desktop/Code/CS/CS.csproj
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to find a solution for all the mac users. All you need to do is add the  two lines listed below to your bash_profile file and everything will run smoothly. If you have trouble doing so please feel free to reply to this answer and i will be more than happy to help you out.

PS: Make sure to replace the 5.0.203 with your version of the .NET sdk

```html
export MSBuildSDKsPath="/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/$(dotnet --5.0.203)/Sdks"
export MSBuildSDKsPath="/usr/share/dotnet/dotnet/sdk/$(dotnet --5.0.203)/Sdks"
```

Comment: The link to the latest version is: https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download  (You will need it to check if `5.0.203` is still the latest....)

Comment: i already had the latest version that wasn't the problem